# How to deal with Questions with More Than 1 Answer and Put Them in Pie Charts in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, pie-chart, mutate

I have a data frame like this:

```
diagnosis <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no")
Q1 <- c("A","NA","A,B",NA,"NA","C,D,A","D","A","B,C,A", "NA")
Q2 <- c("D","NA","D,A,B","C","NA",NA,"A,B,C","A","A","A")
Q3 <- c("B","B,D","C,A,D","A",NA,"A","B,D,A","D","B","NA")
Q4 <- c("B","NA","C","C","C,A","C,B","D","B",NA,"A,B,D")
df <- data.frame(diagnosis, Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)
df
   diagnosis    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4
1        yes     A     D     B     B
2         no    NA    NA   B,D    NA
3        yes   A,B D,A,B C,A,D     C
4        yes  <NA>     C     A     C
5        yes    NA    NA  <NA>   C,A
6         no C,D,A  <NA>     A   C,B
7        yes     D A,B,C B,D,A     D
8         no     A     A     D     B
9         no B,C,A     A     B  <NA>
10        no    NA     A    NA A,B,D
```

As you can see participants can pick more than 1 option for questions. What I want is to create pie charts for the percentages of answers(options) chosen by the participants and compare them between diagnosed and nondiagnosed people.
So, I started with transforming the df to wide to long format with this code below:

```
#Reshape the tibble from wide to long format
df <- df |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4), names_to = "Question", values_to = "Answer") |> 
  group_by(diagnosis, Question) |> 
  mutate(Answer = factor(Answer, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))) |> 
  summarise(percentage = c(prop.table(table(Answer)))) |> 
  mutate(Answer = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

and this is what I get:

```
diagnosis Question percentage Answer
   <chr>     <chr>         <dbl> <chr> 
 1 no        Q1                1 A     
 2 no        Q1                0 B     
 3 no        Q1                0 C     
 4 no        Q1                0 D     
 5 no        Q1                0 E     
 6 no        Q2                1 A     
 7 no        Q2                0 B     
 8 no        Q2                0 C     
 9 no        Q2                0 D     
10 no        Q2                0 E
```

As you can see, the second, and third answers given by the participants are not included. Probably because in this part of the code "mutate(Answer = factor(Answer, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")))" I did not include other combinations.

And then when I get my pie charts this is how it looks:

```
#plot data in pie chart
df |> 
  mutate(percentage = ifelse(percentage == 0, NA, percentage)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = percentage, 
             fill = Answer)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percentage*100), "%")), color = "white", size=2.7, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar("y") +
  facet_grid(diagnosis ~ Question, switch = "both") +
  labs(x = "Diagnosis", y = "Questions") + 
 theme_void()
```

[image: pie charts]

I would like to know how I just let R include all the answer combinations possible for each question as levels.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Pie charts seem like an exceptionally bad choice for questions where respondents can select more than 1 answer. The entire point of a pie chart is that the slices add up to 100%, and that this 100% is comparable from one pie to another. In a case where respondents can select 0, 1, or more answers, what 100% means for a pie chart isn't at all clear - % of responses? % of respondees? I think dodged bar charts with counts for each answer **including** non-responses, would be a much more reasonable representation of the data.

Comment: i conquer with Gregor on using pie-charts for the problem. However, check your code. With `pivot_longer()` you certainly create a long data frame (which works well with ggplot). However, your factor() call does not what you think it does. You will still have answer combinations - in the long format - e.g. "B,D" ... and verify what your factor call does to them. This might explain that you miss certain answers in your plot.